# How to write a bash function that saves user input to new variable names

Tags: bash, shell, terminal

Does anyone know how to convert this mac bash statement into a reusable function?
`test $var || echo -e "\n$(tput bold)Question for User$(tput sgr0)" && read var`

I've got about 30 similar statements in a row and am trying to make it a bit more efficient. I'm thinking this function would be fired with something like this:
`userInput "Question for User" var`

Comment: Why not use an associative array - typeset -A values. You can easily pass array indexes into a function and  doing a unset when done does a 100% clean up of used members.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your script runs under bash (not zsh or dash or...), you can do this:

```
newline=$'\n'
tput_bold=$(tput bold)
tput_sgr0=$(tput sgr0)
userInput() {
    if [[ -z "${!2}" ]]; then
        read -p "${newline}${tput_bold}$1${tput_sgr0}" $2
    fi
}

userInput "Question for User" var
```

Notes: The critical trick here is to use `${! }` to do an indirect variable reference -- the `!` makes it essentially dereference twice, so `2` -> `var` -> the value of `$var`. Also, `echo -e` is unreliable; depending on a variety of factors, it might interpret escape characters in the string, or it might print "-e " as part of the output. bash's `read -p` (prompt) option is much better. Finally, as @l0b0 suggested, I ran the `tput` command just twice and put the results in variables (along with newline, needed because I'm not using `echo -e`).

Comment: Dang. This is similar to what I just figured out. Gonna have to try this out to see if I like it better than my code.

Comment: Chose this solution, since the function is one line shorter than the code I hacked up previously. Very similar concept, but slightly more concise.

Answer (score 1):

Some hints:

- [Use More Quotes™](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes). `test` on its own (which is the same command as `test $var` if `var` is empty) is falsy and `test some_string` in general is truthy (as long as the string doesn't contain special characters used in `test` expressions).
- The `tput` stuff is simply string formatting and has no other side effects, so they can be put into variables to avoid two forks per run.
- [You cannot pass the variable name to a function and have `read` populate it.](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashWeaknesses) You're best off `printf`ing the user response in the function and capturing the string in the caller.
- Use `read`'s `-p` option if available.

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to piece together this function, which does exactly what I'm trying to do:

```
userInput () {
    if [[ ${!2} == "" ]]; then
        echo -e "\n$(tput bold)$1$(tput sgr0)" && read newinput
        printf -v $2 "$newinput"
    fi
}
```

This function tests to see if the variable has a value. If it doesn't, then it captures that information from the user and sets the variable value. Here's a few examples.

If $name isn't set, then this command captures and sets it:

```
userInput "Enter Your Name" name`

Enter Your Name
John Doe

echo $name
John Doe
```

If $name is already set, then running this function will do nothing.

```
name="Frank Smith";
userInput "Your Name" name

// Function does nothing, since $name is set

echo $name
Frank Smith
```

I've read it depends on some sort of parameter expansion / substitution, but can't really explain what that is or why this works.